# How to change URL in Selenium without opening new tab (python)?

Tags: python, selenium, url, webdriver

I saw some `.navigate()` functions to do that in java but it's not in python.

So, how can I just change the URL of currently opened window without opening a new tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call `driver.get('yourURL')` again. Example:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://google.com')
print(driver.current_url)
driver.get('https://gmail.com/')
print(driver.current_url)
```

Output:

```
https://www.google.com/
https://www.google.com/intl/id/gmail/about/#
```